# Prove the probability inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

$Let \quad \xi > 0$ random variable, $D(\xi) \leq 2$

The question is:

Is it right that: (*)$P(E(\xi)-2 \leq \xi \leq 2 \cdot E(\xi) + 1) \geq \frac{1}{2}$?

My solution is:

$P(E(\xi)-2 \leq \xi \leq 2 \cdot E(\xi) + 1) = P(E(\xi) - \xi \geq 2) - P(\xi - 2 \cdot E(\xi) \geq 1)$

From Chebyshev's inequality and $D(\xi)\leq 2$ we have $P(E(\xi) - \xi \geq 2) \leq \frac{1}{2}$

Then we have that $P(\xi - 2 \cdot E(\xi) \geq 1) = 0$ if (*) is right.

But how can we prove or disprove that fact?

I confused about $2 \cdot E(\xi)$, we cant't apply Chebyshev's or Markov's inequality if I'm right.

Comment: Is $D(\xi)$ the variance of $\xi$?

Comment: Yes, variance or $\sigma^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With usual notations $m=\mathbb{E}(\xi)$ and $\sigma^2=D(\xi).$ Denote $Z=\frac{\xi-m}{\sigma}$. Therefore if $m\geq 1$
$$\Pr(m-2<m+\sigma Z<2m+1)=\Pr(-\frac{2}{\sigma}<Z<
\frac{m+1}{\sigma})>\Pr(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}<Z<
\frac{m+1}{\sqrt{2}})>\Pr(Z^2<2)>1/2$$ since $Pr(Z^2>2)\leq 1/2$ by Tchebychev.

If $m\leq 1$ then by Markov$$\Pr(m-2<\xi<2m+1)=\Pr(0<\xi<2m+1)=1-\Pr(\xi>2m+1)>1-\frac{m}{2m+1}>\frac{1}{2}.$$